# Failing to create a SBT project in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, intellij-scala

I tried to convert a Scala project (without SBT) to an SBT project and I am struggling to run it in IntelliJ. I have Scala 2.11 and Java 8 installed correctly but still no luck. I think there is a configuration with IntelliJ which I am not doing correctly. I appreciate any help or hint.

`build.sbt`:

```
name := "hw2"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

unmanagedBase := baseDirectory.value / "libs"
```

Directory structure:

```
.
├── build.sbt
├── libs
│   └── rhino-1.7.7.2.jar
├── output
├── project
│   ├── build.properties
│   ├── project
│   └── target
├── src
│   └── main
├── target
│   ├── global-logging
│   ├── scala-2.11
│   ├── streams
│   └── task-temp-directory
└── test
    ├── simple.js
    └── while.js
```

IntelliJ doesn't recognize the `build.sbt` file

[image]

[Repository URL](https://github.com/amir734jj/cs738/tree/c2bd33beb3a7652a5fb9678f395f1dcf604abaff)

Comment: There are always problems doing this it is a major PITA. Does SBT build on the command line? You installed the ij plugin right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import it from existing sources:

[image]

Then choose `sbt`:

[image]